# ImageView cropped top and bottom and fixed aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-custom-view, crop, aspect-ratio

I need an ImageView with the following requirements:

- Its height has to be 50% of its width
- The image has to be cropped at the top and the bottom

So i would need something like this [Custom View by JakeWharton](https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/2856179) combined with something like this [CropImageView library](https://github.com/cesards/CropImageView). But the latter library only support either `centerTop` or `centerBottom` and not both.

I would like to create an own CustomView for this issue. But I don't know how. Can who is good at implementing custom views give me some hints how to do that? Or does someone know a library with which I can satisfy both requirements?

Comment: no need for any custom views: just use scale type == MATRIX and setup the correct `Matrix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I use a custom ImageView with proportional height. In the onMeasure method the actual height is always replaced with a height proportional to the measured width.

   ```
   public class ImageViewWithProportionalHeight extends ImageView {

       private float mProportion;

       public ImageViewWithProportionalHeight(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);

           TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ProportionalHeight, 0, 0);
           mProportion = attributes.getFloat(R.styleable.ProportionalHeight_heightProportionToWidth, 0);
           attributes.recycle();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
           int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
           int height = (int) (width * mProportion);

           super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
       }

   }
   ```

   You could of course hardcode the proportion directly in that file. To be more flexible you can use styleable attributes. Then you need a resource XML file to define your custom attributes.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <declare-styleable name="ProportionalHeight">
           <attr name="heightProportionToWidth" format="float" />
       </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
   ```

   Now you can use your view in a normal layout XML file using your custom attribute

   ```
   <your.package.name.ImageViewWithProportionalHeight
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:heightProportionToWidth="0.5" />
   ```

---

2. You may use a [scale type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) on your ImageView like CENTER_CROP. This does not necessarily only crop the top and bottom, but it fills the ImageView and centers the image in it. If this is not a solution for you, you should be careful with the aspect ratio of the images your loading into the view. It may be that you get empty areas

Comment: Thanks, using the custom ``ImageView`` and ``CENTER_CROP`` has made what I wanted.